# How to remove whitespace when working with empty img src in html

Tags: html, groovy

I have two image tags, one for the left side and one for the right side. The image on the left will always be populated, but the image on the right may or may not be populated. In the case it is not populated, the image src will be empty (i.e. img src = ""). However, this creates a whitespace where the image should be. How can I go around removing this? I've tried to use alt = "" and I've also tried to set height and width, etc. to 0, but the whitespace is always there (just smaller).

[image]

Not sure if I can directly remove this in the HTML or if I have to code this in (using Groovy/Java).

Comment: why not put a sample code (HTML + css) of what you already have?  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

respectfully you can give it a display of none in case `src` attribute is empty using javascript.
also  you can do it with pure css like:

```css
img[src*=""] {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Was wondering if I could have this as an inline in my html, since this html is written for an email. Would it look something like this

<td bgcolor="${bgColor}" align="right"><img style="height:40px; img[src=""]. {display:none;}" src="${rightImage}"/></td>

Comment: i think it can't work, cause `img[src*=""] ` is a selector and its not going to work in inline mode. no difference using email, you can use this rule as any other styles you have in your template

Answer (score 1):

you can simply make it display none using CSS if the Image src is empty. Just place the below code in your Stylesheet "CSS file"

```
img[src=""], img[src="#"] {display:none;}
```

the above css will apply on all images, if you need to make it specific like only the image in spacific div just add class before that see below.

```
.class_name img[src=""], img[src="#"] { display:none;}
```